# Using ingress in multi namespace cluster AKS

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I have a cluster, I created namespaces for different teams. Then, I tried to apply an ingress to one namespace with this command `kubectl apply -f ing2_dev_plat.yaml -n namespace_name`.

After, this error was thrown. How can I properly configure the work of ingress controller in several namespaces?

Nginx ingress contoller service is in default namespace.

```
Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "ing2_dev_plat.yaml": admission webhook "validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io" denied the request:
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error: exit status 1
2022/02/11 09:17:49 [warn] 3250#3250: the "http2_max_field_size" directive is obsolete, use the "large_client_header_buffers" directive instead in /tmp/nginx-cfg1414424955:143
nginx: [warn] the "http2_max_field_size" directive is obsolete, use the "large_client_header_buffers" directive instead in /tmp/nginx-cfg1414424955:143
2022/02/11 09:17:49 [warn] 3250#3250: the "http2_max_header_size" directive is obsolete, use the "large_client_header_buffers" directive instead in /tmp/nginx-cfg1414424955:144
nginx: [warn] the "http2_max_header_size" directive is obsolete, use the "large_client_header_buffers" directive instead in /tmp/nginx-cfg1414424955:144
2022/02/11 09:17:49 [warn] 3250#3250: the "http2_max_requests" directive is obsolete, use the "keepalive_requests" directive instead in /tmp/nginx-cfg1414424955:145
nginx: [warn] the "http2_max_requests" directive is obsolete, use the "keepalive_requests" directive instead in /tmp/nginx-cfg1414424955:145
2022/02/11 09:17:49 [emerg] 3250#3250: duplicate location "/" in /tmp/nginx-cfg1414424955:1045
nginx: [emerg] duplicate location "/" in /tmp/nginx-cfg1414424955:1045
nginx: configuration file /tmp/nginx-cfg1414424955 test failed
```

[image]

Comment: can you post the content of ing2_dev_plat.yaml please ?

Comment: `nginx: [emerg] duplicate location "/" in /tmp/nginx-cfg1414424955:1045` may indicate you have the same location defined twice. Do you have any other Ingress resources with `path: /`?

Comment: @p10l Yes you was right. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in my comment under the question:

```text
nginx: [emerg] duplicate location "/" in /tmp/nginx-cfg1414424955:1045
```

may indicate you have the same location defined twice.

If you have any other Ingress resources with `path: /`, you have to edit those accordingly.

You can get all Ingress resources with their paths with

```text
kubectl get ingress -A -o=jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{"\t"}{.spec.rules[*].http.paths[*].path}{"\n"}{end}'
```